# Unable to coerce to a formatted date - Cassandra timestamp type

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, spring-data-cassandra

I have the values stored for **timestamp type** column in cassandra table in format of
2018-10-27 11:36:37.950000+0000 (GMT date).
I get **Unable to coerce '2018-10-27 11:36:37.950000+0000' to a formatted date (long)** when I run below query to get data.

```
select create_date from test_table where create_date='2018-10-27 11:36:37.950000+0000' allow filtering;
```

How to get the query working if the data is already stored in the table (of format, 2018-10-27 11:36:37.950000+0000) and also perform range (>= or <=) operations on **create_date** column?

I tried with `create_date='2018-10-27 11:36:37.95Z',` 
`create_date='2018-10-27 11:36:37.95'` `create_date='2018-10-27 11:36:37.95'`too.

Is it possible to perform filtering on this kind of timestamp type data?

P.S. Using cqlsh to run query on cassandra table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first case, the problem is that you specify timestamp with microseconds, while Cassandra operates with milliseconds - try to remove the three last digits - `.950` instead of `.950000` (see this [document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refDateTimeFormats.html) for details).  The timestamps are stored inside Cassandra as 64-bit number, and then formatted when printing results using the format specified by `datetimeformat` options of `cqlshrc` (see [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshUsingCqlshrc.html#cqlshUsingCqlshrc__cqlshrcDisplay)).  Dates without explicit timezone will require that default timezone is specified in `cqlshrc`.

Regarding your question about filtering the data - this query will work only for small amounts of data, and on bigger data sizes will most probably timeout, as it will need to scan all data in the cluster. Also, the data won't be sorted correctly, because sorting happens only inside single partition.

If you want to perform such queries, then maybe the Spark Cassandra Connector will be the better choice, as it can effectively select required data, and then you can perform sorting, etc. Although this will require much more resources.

I recommend to take [DS220](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220) course from DataStax Academy to understand how to model data for Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks! Alex. I already tried removing the three last digits - .950 instead of .950000, but no luck. I was also checking the datastax reference to check how cassandra stores and formats timestamps. Seems like I also need to check in changing the HH:MM:SS.sss to other timezone timestamps (maybe like actual format before it was stored in cassandra).

Comment: As I said, the data is stored as long, not as particular date format - when the data is submitted it's parsed from the string into long, and when retrieved - converted from long to string

Comment: just checked, for my test it worked just fine: `create table t1(tm timestamp primary key, t text);` then `insert into t1(tm, t) values(toTimestamp(now()), 't');` then `select * from t1 where tm = '2018-10-27 18:01:54.738+0000';` selected the data (your time will be different)

Comment: Yes, I tried again. It worked after removing the three last digits - .950 instead of .950000. I think I overlooked at it by querying for wrong date or format earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is works for me

```sql
var datetime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss");
                var query = $"SET  updatedat = '{datetime}' WHERE ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't answer the exact question... plus it's not the best practice to use string substitution - for performance reasons it's better to use prepared statements, and bind correct data type instead, and driver will do correct coercion